# Android Studio BaseGameUtils build error

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have the following error message when I try to build my project after implementing BaseGameUtils:

> :BaseGameUtils:extractReleaseAnnotations FAILED
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':BaseGameUtils:extractReleaseAnnotations'.
>
> > originalComplianceLevel

Answer (score 0):

I've searched and returned: "You'll have to use 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT for robovm for now if you want the fix."

See this link [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/4094) to see the complete post.

Comment: Isn't this a fix only for iOS?

Comment: I think it is for Android. But please do a quick look to the post.